# Android Notification Shows Even Though It's Time Has Already Passed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification

So for example even though it's 19:40 when I create notification and set it's time to 19:00 it shows as fast as possible after creation. My code to create notif. is as follows:

```
private void setNotificationTime(int hour,int minute,int position){
    Log.i("NotificationValues",hour+":"+minute+" ,"+position+" "); //Testing purposes
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, position, intent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

What's more is that if I set the notification time to the future it works fine.

Comment: If you are trying to set the event for the *next* 19:00, then check to see if your configured `calendar` is in the past. If it is, then `add()` 1 day to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @CommonsWare commented I first have to check whether the time is already in the past using method such like this one

```
private boolean compareTime(int hour,int minute) throws Exception{
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String now[] = parser.format(new Date()).split(":");
    int hourNow = Integer.parseInt(now[0]);
    int minuteNow = Integer.parseInt(now[1]);
    if(hourNow>=hour && minuteNow>minute){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then something like this:

```
if(compareTime()){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}
```